# JQuery/Javascript RDF plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, rdf

Any ideas about JQuery plugins/Javascript libraries for working with RDF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for [RDF Query](http://code.google.com/p/rdfquery/) which "is an easy-to-use Javascript library for RDF-related processing".  There are lots of examples of use of it at the author's blog: [Jeni's Musings](http://www.jenitennison.com/blog/).

Comment: Good one, the examples sell this quite nicely!

Answer (score 4):

There's also the RDF parser included in the [Tabulator](http://brondsema.net/blog/index.php/2006/11/25/javascript_rdfparser_from_tabulator) project, and a couple of newer solutions are [jOWL](http://jowl.ontologyonline.org/) and [Jstle](http://github.com/dnewcome/jstle).

Overall, however, [rdfQuery](http://code.google.com/p/rdfquery/) is probably the most comprehensive solution available at this time.

Answer (score 1):

There's this JavaScript [RDF parser](http://www.jibbering.com/rdf-parser/). At least, you can start from it. Or, [RdfPlugin](http://code.google.com/p/rdfquery/wiki/RdfPlugin) that allows you to create, store and query RDF triples in a jQuery-like way.

Comment: I have tried RDF parser with some success, but the RDFquery seems more like what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tiny RDF parser: it doesn't support the full RDF spec, but it is OK for me.
See http://anybody.cephb.fr/perso/lindenb/rdfjs/rdf.xul (requires firefox for XUL )